# Make an item required in Joi if it is set in another object of that array

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I have an array of objects with the same structure. Is it possible, if an item in one object is set to make it required in all other objects?

```
const arr = [
  {
    item1: 1,
    item2: 2
  },
  {
    item1: 3
  }
]
```

In this example it would be an error, because in the second object item2 isn't set though it is present in the first object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can specify the schema of an object inside an array. Sample code

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const objectSchema = Joi.object({
  item1: Joi.number().required(),
  item2: Joi.number().required()
})

const arraySchema = Joi.array().items(objectSchema);

const invalidInput = [{
  item1: 1,
  item2: 2
}, {
  item1: 1,
}];


const result = Joi.validate(invalidInput, arraySchema);
console.log(result);
```

The output will show an error

`{ ValidationError: "value" at position 1 fails because [child "item2" fails because ["item2" is required]]`

Comment: I don't think that this would serve my needs, because it will show an error with this input, too: `const invalidInput = [{
  item1: 1
}, {
  item1: 1
}];` I only want to have an error, when item2 is set in at least one object and not set in another object of that array.